# JAXB: How to keep consecutive spaces as they are in source XML during unmarshalling

Tags: space, preserve

I am using JAXB to unmarshall an XML message. It seems to replace multiple consecutive spaces by a single space.

```
<testfield>this is a       test<\testfield>
```

(several spaces between a and test)

upon unmarshalling, the above becomes:

```
this is test
```

How do I keep consecutive spaces as they are in source XML?

Answer (score 0):

From the msdn page:

> Document authors can use the xml:space attribute to identify portions
>   of documents where white space is considered important. Style sheets
>   can also use the xml:space attribute as a hook to preserve white space
>   in presentation. However, because many XML applications do not
>   understand the xml:space attribute, its use is considered advisory.

You can try adding xml:space="preserve" so it doesn't replace the spaces

```
<poem xml:space="default">
<author xml:space="default">
<givenName xml:space="default">Alix</givenName>
<familyName xml:space="default">Krakowski</familyName>
</author>
<verse xml:space="preserve">
<line xml:space="preserve">Roses   are  red,</line>
<line xml:space="preserve">Violets  are  blue.</line>
<signature xml:space="default">-Alix</signature>
</verse>
</poem>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx